# Unknown field name 'SubmitOptions' after Perforce upgrade

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I just migrated/upgraded from a Windows 2003 Perforce 2009.2 installation to a Windows 2008 R2 2010.2 box and noted that after the upgrade, the only issue that seems to present is the inability to create/edit workspaces from the UI - because it tries to set the SubmitOptions parameter and throws

```
Error at line 0 of field 'SubmitOptions' in client specification.
Unknown field name 'SubmitOptions'.
```

Yes, I'm able to create/edit client spec using `p4 client`, as long as I don't try to include the `SubmitOptions` parameter.

As far as I can tell, all aspects of the upgrade succeeded (p4d replacement, `p4d -xu` to upgrade the database, license in place, etc.)

Any ideas?  Haven't found a whisper of this issue online (and my Google-fu is pretty good...)

**Updates:** 
Output from `p4 spec -o client` (I've removed all comments)

```
# A Perforce Spec Specification.
Fields:
    301 Client word 32 key
    302 Update date 20 always
    303 Access date 20 always
    304 Owner word 32 optional
    305 Host word 32 optional
    306 Description text 128 optional
    307 Root line 64 required
    308 AltRoots llist 64 optional
    309 Options line 64 optional
    310 LineEnd select 12 optional
    311 View wlist 64 optional

Words:
    View 2

Formats:
    Client 1 normal
    Update 2 L
    Access 4 L
    Owner 3 R
    Host 5 R
    LineEnd 0 L

Values:
    Options noallwrite/allwrite,noclobber/clobber,nocompress/compress,unlocked/locked,nomodtime/modtime,normdir/rmdir
    LineEnd local/unix/mac/win/share
```

Comment: What does 'p4 spec -o client' say?

Comment: Also, which UI are you using (p4v vs. p4win) and which version?

Comment: @Bryan, this appears to be the key point - I'm creating an answer based on what I learned this weekend, and while submitting some changes solved the issue, I still don't really know how/why/when the SubmitOptions went missing.  Last upgrade was 2009 at some point (before I managed the server), but they weren't there then either.

Comment: @jhwist, our devs are split between the two clients - and from what I hear, p4win did allow them to set revertunchanged.  p4v (2010.1) is what most others were using, and the SubmitOptions dropdown didn't even appear prior to the upgrade. Post upgrade, it appeared, but would be the failure upon submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, submitting the following additions to the client spec resolved the issue:

```
Fields:
    313 SubmitOptions select 25 optional
    314 Stream line 64 optional
Formats:
    SubmitOptions 0 L
Values:
    SubmitOptions submitunchanged/submitunchanged+reopen/revertunchanged/revertunchanged+reopen/leaveunchanged/leaveunchanged+reopen
```

I added those to the previous values and submitted the changes using the combination of

```
p4 configure set spec.custom=1

p4 spec -i client < fixedp4clientspec.txt
```

The first command was required because I received an error of `"Custom spec of type 'client' is not allowed. Set spec.custom=1 to override."` when I tried to update the spec without it.  And I don't actually know that line 314 was needed to address this problem, but it was suggested when diffed against a spec that worked elsewhere.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Can you contact Perforce support to clarify what that line 314 does?

Comment: @jhwist, I wonder if it has to do with the Streams that Perforce is introducing in it's next version.  http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=4615

Comment: @jhwist, the word I got back from Perforce Support was they were "pretty sure this is related to advance testing of [the Streams] feature".  Pretty vague, and there is definitely no publicly available documentation on this unsupported command (`p4 spec`). Hope that's enough for ya, since that's what I got!

Comment: It sounds like you have a custom client spec. You probably don't need it. You can remove it by 'p4 spec -d client', I believe. Then you'll get the default client spec, which will have all the fields that match your server version.