# Unable to create a workspace after upgrading Perforce server from 2017 to 2023

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec

I recently upgraded our team's Perforce server from version 2017.1 to 2023.1 Windows. We have a fairly basic server configuration and the upgrade was almost seamless. We've had no issues with existing clients since the upgrade, about 2 weeks ago.

However, while creating a new workspace or updating the depot mappings for an existing workspace on P4V, it throws the following error:
"Unable to create a workspace named ''.
Error at line 0 of field 'Options' in client specification.
Value for field 'Options' must be one of submitunchanged/submitunchanged+reopen/revertunchanged/revertunchanged+reopen/leaveunchanged/leaveunchanged+reopen."

Below are the client specs. Result of `p4 client`:

```
Client: xyz

Update: 2023/08/10 14:25:09

Access: 2023/08/10 14:25:09

Owner:  abc

Host:   xyz

Description:
    Created by abc.

Root:   c:\Users\User

Options:    submitunchanged

LineEnd:    local

View:
    //depot/... //xyz/...
```

Result of `p4 spec -o client`:

```
Fields:
        301 Client word 32 key
        302 Update date 20 always
        303 Access date 20 always
        304 Owner word 32 optional
        305 Host word 32 optional
        306 Description text 128 optional
        307 Root line 64 required
        308 AltRoots llist 64 optional
        313 Options select 25 optional
        310 LineEnd select 12 optional
        314 Stream line 64 optional
        316 StreamAtChange line 64 optional
        315 ServerID line 64 always
        318 Type select 10 optional
        319 Backup select 10 optional
        311 View wlist 64 optional
        317 ChangeView llist 64 optional

Words:
        View 2

Formats:
        Client 1 normal
        Update 2 L
        Access 4 L
        Owner 3 R
        Host 5 R
        Options 0 L
        LineEnd 0 L

Values:
        Options submitunchanged/submitunchanged+reopen/revertunchanged/revertunchanged+reopen/leaveunchanged/leaveunchanged+reopen
        LineEnd local/unix/mac/win/share
        Type writeable/readonly/graph/partitioned
        Backup enable/disable
```

I followed a modified version of the solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076338/unknown-field-name-submitoptions-after-perforce-upgrade]. I added 'SubmitOptions' to the client spec but that resulted in this error.

> Error in spec specification. Builtin field  cannot be changed.

Any suggestions? Are there other specs that need to be inspected?

Comment: you have perforce support?   If so, use it.
Even if you don't have support, might give them an email anyway as this is a bug.
Make sure you have a good checkpoint.   Now.

Answer (score 0):

One of the steps in the upgrade process was failing because: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." I overlooked this error in the log.txt file. Excluding P4ROOT from anti-virus scan and then upgrading the server resolved my issue.